# Not updating cookie values

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies

In my project, I have written code for creating a cookie.

I need to retrieve its value on another page. Here's what I've tried, on the Login.aspx button click event:

```
Guid guid_string_Id = System.Guid.NewGuid();
 string newID = guid_string_Id.ToString();

Response.Cookies["name"]["Font"] = newID;
Response.Redirect("page2.aspx");
```

On page load for page2.aspx,

```
if (Request.Cookies["name"] != null)
{
  string new_ID;
  if (Request.Cookies["name"]["Font"] != null)
  {
    new_ID = Request.Cookies["name"]["Font"]; 
  }
}
else
{
  Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
}
```

I always find that cookies value remains same .what will be the problem?

In my web.config, I have set:

```
<sessionState mode="InProc"  regenerateExpiredSessionId="true" stateNetworkTimeout="30" sqlCommandTimeout="30" cookieless="false" timeout="30">
</sessionState>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your Login.aspx page you just need to add a cookie to the cookies collection:

```
Guid guid_string_Id = System.Guid.NewGuid();
string newID = guid_string_Id.ToString();

var cookie = new HttpCookie("font", newID);
Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
Response.Redirect("page2.aspx");
```